# ag-grid : autoscroll to selected row is not working in enterprise

Tags: angular, ag-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnLCq.png)

As you can see in the image.

When the grid reloads the 2nd and 3rd grid selection not displayed on the screen.

But when i scroll down to the grid i can see it is selected. this problem occurs in enterprise because (may be the row is not on the screen that time as enterprise shows 100 rows at a time). anyone handle this situation

for each node i am selecting the row like this but it is not auto visible on the screen

```
setTimeout(() => {
        if (node.selectedChildNode) {
          params.api.forEachNode((item: any) => {
            if (item.data === node.selectedChildNode) {
              item.setSelected(true, true);
            }
          });
        }
      }, 0);
```

Comment: please post a sample of your code so we can help

Comment: @PratikBhat edited

Answer (score 9):

As per the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#scrolling), you will also need to scroll to that row using gridapi method `ensureIndexVisible`

```
    if (item.data === node.selectedChildNode) {
              item.setSelected(true, true);
             params.api.ensureIndexVisible(item.rowIndex);

}
```

Here is an [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-gallery/#expanding-groups-vertical-scroll-location)

Comment: i have checked it. how did you call the ensureIndexVisible? it is undefined also this method is not in item.ensureIndexVisible this is also undefined

Comment: ensureIndexVisible  is a gridApi method.

Comment: ensureIndexVisible yes i have used it now, but not able to replicate this because at that time the grid row is not visible as on scroll the rows are loaded on the screen